# Implementation of Redux-Search with components

Tags: javascript, redux, react-redux

**Summary:**

**Now that this problem is solved, I'll do a blog post with re-creation and solution**

Adding Redux-Search to my app.  I've got the store setup properly, my redux dev tools show the search action kicking off on `init` and receiving a proper result, but when I'm actually trying to search the resource using the value submitted with an input field, I'm not getting anything returned.  I'm entirely stuck and I've tried a bunch of different structures to try and get ANY result to return in the component console.log.  I suppose I just don't understand how the reselect package is working, how to pass the text to it properly, and how to grab the result in my component.  If I can get over that hurdle and see something returned from the action creator, I'll be able to take it from there.

Here's my code:

**Reducers/Data.js**
To give background on this file.  I have two reducers.  One called Auth, one called Data (in separate files).  Each has their own initial state.  The initital state shown here is a portion of that defined in data.js.

```
import things from '../data/things';

const initialState = {
  statusText: null,
  thing: null,
  resources: {
    things,
  },
}
```

**Data/Things.js**
This is an example of the data I'm importing into initialState in the data.js file.

```
const things = [
  {
    id: 1,
    name: "example name 1",
  },
...
```

**Reducers/Index.js**

```
import auth from './auth';
import data from './data';

const rootReducer = combineReducers({
  routing: routerReducer,
  /* your reducers */
  search: searchReducer,
  auth,
  data,
});

export default rootReducer;
```

**Store/ConfigureStore.js**

```
import rootReducer from '../reducers'; 

const enhancer = composeWithDevTools(
  applyMiddleware(thunkMiddleware, ...debugware),
  reduxSearch({
    resourceIndexes: {
      things: ['name'],
    },
    resourceSelector: (resourceName, state) => {
      return state.data.resources[resourceName];
    },
  }),
);

export default function configureStore(initialState) {
  const store = createStore(
    rootReducer,
    initialState,
    enhancer,
  );
```

**Component**

The console.log `` console.log(`explore search: ${selectors.thingIds}`); `` is really the only part I need to get working.  I'm just trying to return ANY results that come back from the action creator `searchThings` and that should lead me in the right direction.

```
const actions = {
  searchThings: createSearchAction('things'),
};

@connect(selectors, actions)
export class ExploreSearch extends Component {
  render() {
    console.log(`explore search: ${selectors.thingIds}`);

    return (
      <div>
        <Search
          placeholder="input search text"
          enterButton="Search"
          onSearch={(value) => actions.searchThings(value)}
          style={{ width: 200 }}
        />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

**Component part that I don't understand**
I'm aware there is no way this code is right.  I left it in a pretty dishelved state somewhere between the first simple example bvaughn and the more complex example.  However, if someone can explain where I'm going wrong?

```
const resources = (state) => state.data.resources;
const things = createSelector([resources], (resources) => resources.things);

const { text, result } = getSearchSelectors({
  resourceName: 'things',
  resourceSelector: (resourceName, state) => state.data.resources[resourceName],
});

const selectors = createSelector(
  [result, things, text],
  (result, things, text) => ({
    thingIds: result,
    things,
    searchText: text,
  }),
);
```

Examples I've followed/helpful resources:

- https://github.com/bvaughn/redux-search (Basic example of component/store)
- https://github.com/bvaughn/redux-search/tree/master/website (more advanced example from the developers demo.
- https://bvaughn.github.io/redux-search/ (The demo)

Here's the init returning properly...so as far as I can tell I've setup the store correctly?:

[image: Picture of the receiveResult]

Here is a picture of the state of my store by calling `console.log(store.getState());` at the top level.  This shows that it's under data.resources as far as I can tell.
[image]

Once I figure this sucker out I'm going to write an article to try to patch up the documentation some for those who want to use this library.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first problem is that the redux-search `SEARCH` reducer isn't triggered when your app's "Search" button is clicked. (I can see a debug and see that it's never reached.) That's because your click handler is calling the *unconnected* method `actions.searchThings(value)` rather than using the *connected* method `this.props.searchThings(value)`.

The second problem is related. Your console log is referencing the *unconnected* `selectors.thingIds` rather than the *connected* `this.props.thingIds`.

So the fix is:
[image]

After doing this, I see the ids I would expect being logged to the console.

You could hook this up to your list like so:
[image]

Comment: Data key comes from the way my reducers are setup.  I have two primary files.  One that's called `auth.js` and one called `data.js` which I import into my `index.js` file and combine in my root reducer. Each of those files have an initialstate object. But now having looked at it...I think you're definitely on to something.  None of my state is actually tucked under `state.data.resources` it just happens to be in the data file.  Probably where I got tripped up.  I'll dig into this and let you know what I find.

Comment: I dug into this more.  Upon changing it to state.resources, I was getting undefined errors everywhere.  I also validated the structure of my initialState and data.resources.  Added it to my edits in the original post and a screenshot of the state on app load.  Should help locate the bug a bit better or direction.  My "things" are definitely under state.data.resources.things as far as I can tell.

Comment: Sharing a minimal repro case goes a long way with questions like this. Looking at pictures of code or debuggers isn't the easiest way to help.

Comment: Hey Bvaughn, sorry!  Let me see if I can whip one together for ya.  I really appreciate your guidance here.

Comment: Ahhhh thank you so much!  Just so I'm clear, my connect method hooks the whole component up to redux.  Traditionally I use mapStateToProps and mapDispatchToProps.  In this case my new "selectors" and "actions" are functioning almst the same way, that is...they are mapping these new methods to props.....I just didn't realize it.   Again, you rock and I'll do a write up on my blog for this to hopefully help some others out to save you duplicate questions in the future!

Comment: Glad we got it figured out :)

Comment: @bvaugn  Sort of related question.  I've tweaked my example now to pull in real data.  However, for some reason the searchResults only returns "some" of the available results. (Example: My database contains 8 things, but the receiveResult without any searchText is only showing 5 things).  Each new record I add to my database seems to add another "result" in there [even some that were previously missing].  There seems to be no rhyme or reason why some are being left out.  Is there a result limiter or perhaps a caching mechanism in the redux-search resource index that could be causing this?

Comment: Hard to say. It's possible the tokenizer is treating the strings differently. Or there is something else going on in your Redux setup. I don't really use Redux anymore. Aside from helping with your original question, I haven't used it in years. You might have better luck asking elsewhere.

Comment: fair enough.  Thanks!

Comment: Turns out it was because `results` checks for each and every `id`.  If you've left an id out or deleted it (in the case of my production database which I've deleted a few test records) then, it breaks misses entries.  By changing `results` to `unfilteredResults` in my selectors, it immediately solved the problem.